# Data Filtering and Plotting by User Input

Tags: vba, excel

First of all, I can not add the real data table I have because of the privacy, but I add a similar data by adjusting it for the goals of football leagues, teams and the players.

[image: Example Data Table]

I want to create an interface with VB and let the users choose league, team and player they want to view. I would like to make it possible to select more than one option at the same time, so I think "listbox" would be the best choice.

I also want to let the user select a date range from a tool such as a "time slicer" followed by all of these selections, and then graph the corresponding data to those selections.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use a pivottable, pivotchart with slicer(s) Though I would strongly advise you to have weekly data running down a column not across columns as will be easier for graphing. You could use powerquery to unpivot these columns however.

Comment: I have already tried it by creating three different slicers. But although I make only one selection from the league slicer, all the team options in the team slicer are available.

Comment: Usually this is when your backing data column order is incorrect. Yours appears to be correct. If league comes first then team, and not all teams are present in each league, and both slicers come off the same pivottable report, then when you select a league from the slicer your available teams should subset in the team slicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a pivottable, pivotchart with slicer(s) Though I would strongly advise you to have weekly data running down a column not across columns as will be easier for graphing. You could use powerquery to unpivot these columns however.

Ensure your backing data column order is correct. If league comes first then team, and not all teams are present in each league, and both slicers come off the same pivottable report, then when you select a league from the slicer your available teams should subset in the team slicer.

Example:

[image: Sample data]